# Prove that random variable is nonnegative in example

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with $E[X]=1$ and such that $X1_{\{X\leq 0\}}=0$ a.s.

**Question** Does it follow that $X>0$ a.s.?

**My progress** I tried to write $X=X^+-X^-$, where both $X^+,X^-$ are nonnegative, but I did not make any progress...

Comment: Just consider a nonnegative random variable that can take at most 2 values, say, 0 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that:$$X1_{X\leq0}\neq0\iff X\neq0\wedge X\leq0\iff X<0$$

so that $$X1_{X\leq0}=0\iff X\geq0$$
hence:$$X1_{X\leq0}=0\text{ a.s.}\iff X\geq0\text{ a.s.}$$

Comment: But not necessarily $X > 0$ a.s.